# Razor Javascript dynamic format of anchor not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to dynamically format a Razor Url.Action call with the following code:

```
<script>

function getArchiveDisplayStr(str)
{
    var parts = str.split("-");
    var year = parts[0];
    var month = getMonth(parts[1]);
    return year + " " + month;
}

function getMonth(monthStr)
{
    switch (monthStr)
    {
    case "1":
        return "Jan";

    case "2":
        return "Feb";

    case "3":
        return "Mar";

    case "4":
        return "Apr";

    case "5":
        return "May";

    case "6":
        return "Jun";

    case "7":
        return "Jul";

    case "8":
        return "Aug";

    case "9":
        return "Sep";

    case "10":
        return "Oct";

    case "11":
        return "Nov";

    case "12":
        return "Dec";

    default:
        return "";
    }
}

function createAnchor(monthID)
{
    var displayMonth = getArchiveDisplayStr(monthID);
    return '<a href="@@Url.Action("GetMonth", "Blog", new {monthID="2009-10"})">2009 Sep</a>';
}

</script>

<div>
    <script>
        var anchor = createAnchor('2009-10');
        alert(anchor);
        document.write(anchor);
    </script>
</div>
```

When I run this code the alert box displays:

```
<a href="@@Url.Action("GetMonth", "Blog", new {monthID="2009-10"})">2009 Oct</a>
```

Which is what I expect. However, when I inspect the link I see the following:

```
<a href="@@Url.Action(" getmonth",="" "blog",="" new="" {monthid="2009-10" })"="">2009 Oct</a>
```

I need to create these links on the fly but I do not see why the link is getting set differently than the alert box. What am I missing?

Comment: I missed it until I just saw the answer, I did not remove a test from the createAnchor function. The function look like this:

function createAnchor(monthID)
{
     var displayMonth = getArchiveDisplayStr(monthID);
     return '<a href="@@Url.Action("GetMonth", "Blog", new {monthID="' + monthID + '"})">' + displayMonth + '</a>';
}

The answer posted gives the same results I have been getting, so I am not sure it is the real fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createAnchor(monthID)
{
    var Href='@(Url.Action("GetMonth", "Blog", new {monthID="2009-10"}))';
    var displayMonth = getArchiveDisplayStr(monthID);
    return '<a href="'+ Href +'">2009 Sep</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create the link the way I was, it was best to let Razor do it for me.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.ArchiveList)
 {
     <div class="site-normal no-space-after">
         @if (DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo != null)
         {
             var link = item.Substring(0, 4) + " " + DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(Convert.ToInt32(item.Substring(5, item.Length - 5)));
             @Html.ActionLink(link, "GetMonth", new { monthID = item })
         }
     </div>
 }
```